# Smoother column resize, page reveal animation

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery, animation

I've been working on [this site](http://dev.jthomas80.com).

The designers original inspiration for the column layout came from [this site](http://www.woodwork.nl).  I've been trying to get the animation as smooth as possible, to match the smoothness of the site referenced; but it's still choppy.

```
(function ($ , window, document ) {
    var c,page,href,pagewidth,
        previousTarget = null,
        pageinner = $('#pageinner'),
        body = $(document.body);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            window.history.pushState('#', null, './');
        }
    });

    $(window).on('resize',function() {
        pagewidth = Math.round(($(window).width()));
        console.log(pagewidth);
    }).trigger('resize');

    $(document).on('click', '.close-button', function(event) {
        previousTarget = 'close';
        event.preventDefault();
        switch ($(this).attr('data-page')) {
            case 'foundation':
                $('#bar1').click();
                break;
            case 'social':
                $('#bar2').click();
                break;
            case 'news':
                $('#bar3').click();
                break;
            case 'locker':
                $('#bar4').click();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    });

    $('#bar1').click(function(){
        pageinner.load("<?php echo get_site_url() ?>" + $(this).attr('data-page') + ' #page').show();
        if(this===previousTarget || previousTarget === 'close') {
            c = -(Math.round(pagewidth / 5));
            run(1);
            History.back();
            body.removeClass('page').addClass('home');
            pageinner.addClass('closed').children().remove();
            previousTarget=null;
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#carousel').css({'background':'transparent'});
            c = Math.round(pagewidth / 5);
            run(1);
            history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr("data-page"));
            setTimeout(function(){
                body.removeClass('home').addClass('page');
                pageinner.removeClass('closed');
                $('#bookCarousel').slick({
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '0',
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    focusOnSelect: true,
                    autoplay:false,
                    autoplaySpeed:5000
                });
            },1000);
            previousTarget=this;
            return false;
        }
    });

    function run(b) {
        var d1 = $.Deferred(),d2 = d1,d3 = d1,d4 = d1;

        document.body.classList.add("wait");

        $.when(d1, d2, d3, d4).done(function() {
            document.body.classList.remove("wait");
        });

        switch (b) {
            case 1:
                move('#bar2').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 3).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d1.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar3').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 2).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d2.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar4').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d3.resolve();
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                move('#bar1').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d1.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar2').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d2.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar3').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 2).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d3.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar4').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d4.resolve();
                });
                break;
            case 3:
                move('#bar1').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d1.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar2').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', (c * 2) * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d2.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar3').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', (c * 2) * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d3.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar4').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d4.resolve();
                });
                break;
            case 4:
                move('#bar1').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d1.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar2').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', (c * 2) * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d2.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar3').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', (c * 3) * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d3.resolve();
                });
                move('#bar4').ease('in-out').add('margin-left', (c * 3) * -1).duration(750).end(function () {
                    d4.resolve();
                });
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I've gone through numerous iterations of the code to get it to this point and previous attempts I've posted on Codepen, [here](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/ByjjMv), and [here](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/azvGwm), and [here](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/XJbRwo).

Anyone have any thoughts on what I can do to smooth out the transition further?

Answer (score 1):

If you only support modern browsers, use CSS3 animations instead. And rather than margin-left property, use transform (translateX), as it's one of the best performant properties for animation